# Faucet supposed to stick out this far?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, installation, bathtub

A local plumbing company installed my tub/shower.  In my uneducated opinion, this faucet doesn't look right and seems to be sticking too far out.  Should it look like this?  I don't want to be overly picky, but I did pay a decent chunk of change and want it done right.

[image]
[image]
[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EGmyRhQ1eto  (video of the sleeve sliding back and forth - if it helps to see what's going on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's just.... nasty. The spout looks fine but the faucet is both too far out and not square. There's a large gap at the base that looks like it can leak water into the wall space.

The "plumber" was either drunk, half-asleep or incompetent. There is no excuse for work that sloppy.

Comment: Agreed, the valve body was not set (or "roughed in") correctly.

Comment: Thanks much for validating my concerns.  So when I call to request them back, i can say... what?  The copper needs cut shorter?  Or is it more than that?

Comment: (I think it's pretty darn close to square.  The picture has a weird angle.  And the bottom of the faceplate needs tightened.  Maybe not "perfect", but if there's anyway this can be reaolved without having them take the shower walls off, that would certainly be ideal.

Comment: Seems to be about 1/8" angled down.

Comment: There's an outside chance that a shorter part can be popped in, but more likely the entire mixer unit has to be pushed further into the framing. Sometimes you can attack this from the other side of the wall. Sometimes you can cut a slightly oversized hole in the bath surround wall. Sometimes you have  to do everything over. Good luck.

Comment: The owner of the company came over, saw the work, apologized profusely, and said he'd have his team re-do the entire thing if that's what it took to make absolutely sure it's done right this time.  Thanks again for the advice.

Comment: They're here fixing it, and I'm concerned that they're going to try just pushing it back in a bit or something half-assed.  Is there a way I can determine or know how far back in it SHOULD be?

Answer (score 1):

I never heard of Screw Dave Day, live & learn. Absolutely, get them back to do everything over, free of charge! That picture's all sorts of wrong, except tub spout, & not at all professional! Talk to the Owner of the company!

That faucet needs to go back, at least, 1 full inch & the shaft sleeve is on backwards & should be tight-tight against the escutcheon plate or faceplate & no eye nor camera should be able to see any of that white behind the handle.

The Tub's overflow wasn't done & likely the drain wasn't either. I'm just hoping you got a new & matching shower arm & shower head out of this willfully broken deal.

Comment: Appreciate you taking the time to validate my concerns.   If you have a moment to help me understand what you're saying, I'll be better able to voice my concerns.  The shaft sleeve is on backwards?  I'm linking a YouTube video that shows how it slides.  Would you mind looking and verifying it's backwards?   As far as the "should be tight-tight against the faceplate", are you referring to where the slide-able sleeve goes back through the faceplate hole?  (or in my case slides back close to it).

Comment: You also mentioned "the Tub's overflow wasn't done", but it is on there.  It's my fault it's chrome, not brushed nickle, since I bought the hardware (I did buy it before they put the shower in though, so they knew what they were working with).  Is that all you meant, or is there something else wrong?

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time!  I greatly appreciate it.  And I LOL'd/cried at your "Screw Dave Day" - it sure seems that way.  I've added a link to a video of the faucet sleeve sliding back and forth.

Comment: Nope, it looks like I'm wrong. This one seems to be on right, as the shaft's back looks to be a bigger diameter than the front end. But, there shouldn't be any sliding & it should go inside the faceplate's hole...after they properly recess the entire valve. Typically, there's just 1-inch, at the most, of shaft showing (wall thickness will determine this). Oh, it was Dave Screwing Dave Day, that's why I hadn't heard of it. Oh well, you can always screw-on a matching tub overflow later. Everything really should match in order to be acceptable to guests. Post the outcome too, please.

Comment: Right - I'm not worried about the matching metal for now - I'll certainly get a new overflow cover, but that seems the least of my concerns at the moment :(  So it sounds like everyone is in agreement that the big thing I need to request them to come back and do is to move the faucet back into the wall further so there's no big gap between the sleeve and the faceplate, and so you can't see the white behind the handle.  Sound right?  Thanks again for your time.  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Almost, it's more like no big gap between the faceplate & the handle. That sleeve usually slips in from the backside of the face plate & then water seals & locks itself. Then, the faceplate & shaft sleeve go on as 1-piece.

Comment: The owner of the company came over, saw the work, apologized profusely, and said he'd have his team re-do the entire thing if that's what it took to make absolutely sure it's done right this time.  Thanks again for the advice.

Comment: So glad to hear it!!! I'd use his company again in the future. Hopefully, the guy who did it does it again, of course with actual instruction & supervision this time so he can learn & see how he left you. He wouldn't want it in his house & should treat people with much more respect. He won't be a plumber for long if he doesn't start learning that quick.

Comment: They're here fixing it, and I'm concerned that they're going to try just pushing it back in a bit or something half-assed.  Is there a way I can determine or know how far back in it SHOULD be?

Comment: Sure, post an update to your question here with the final result picture(s). The owner sounded quite shocked at how blatantly bad it was, so we expect a very apparent improvement. The good news is that they can't just sledgehammer it back into the wall without very easily breaking everything behind the wall. But, we'll see if the owner is genuine or just a good actor slime.

Answer (score 0):

A possible option, probably less desirable than a full rebuild - but easier to get agreement on, is to have a spacer ring put in behind all the visible faucet hardware. That is, between the large diameter circle and the wall.

It is possible that the valve body behind the shower wall is too far forward. The spacer ring would take up some of the extra space.

EDIT: Just looked at the video.  I suggest finding out if a longer sleeve is available from the manufacturer.